# Workflow won't fire on list attachment update

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, attachments

We have a SharePoint 2010 list with attachments, and if the user simply views the list item and updates the attachment, the workflow email action fails to fire.  The only way updates will fire the workflow on the list item is when the user actually updates the list item fields values.

We need to be notified of anything tied to the list item is updated...form fields or attachment.

Please advise how we can get attachment updates to fire the workflow.

Version history is updated if user views item + updates the attachment...but the workflow doesn't fire to send the email notification.

Comment: what account is the workflow running under? if its system account it would not trigger! the workflow should trigger if the attachment is uploaded as its still changing the list item properties (causing an update event).

Comment: It's firing under the account of the logged in user.